# Increase LXD ZFS Loop Storage

Tags: zfs, lxd

Im trying to increase LXD ZFS Loop Storage, from 10GB to 700GB, How can I ?

```
NAME       SIZE  ALLOC   FREE  EXPANDSZ   FRAG    CAP  DEDUP  HEALTH  ALTROOT
test-tao  9.94G  6.95G  2.98G         -    46%    69%  1.00x  ONLINE  -
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To expand the size of a ZFS pool you need to add more VDEVs to it. As the ZFS pool grows, the ZFS filesystems on it will automatically have new space available. With ZFS you don't need to preallocate, format or chose a filesystem size in advance. Every filesystem in the pool see the available space and can use it.

Every new VDEV will add to the existing storage capacity and data will automatically be striped across all available VDEVs. A VDEV is an abstraction of phisical media and can represent an actual partition of a disk, an entire single disk, a mirror of disks or a RAID-Z (distributed parity, similar to RAID 5). Normally you would add the same type of VDEV you already have in the existing pool. If the pool is made of a single disk, you add more single disk VDEVs (unless you need to upgrade to mirrored VDEVs, which you could do); if your pool is made of mirrors, you add more mirror VDEVs; and so on. There is no point in mixing different types of VDEVS on the same pool.

For example, to add a single disk VDEV to your pool, you use the command:

```
sudo zpool add test-tao /dev/<disk-name>
```

Or to add a mirror VDEV:

```
sudo zpool add test-tao mirror /dev/<disk-0-name> /dev/<disk-1-name>
```

To learn more about VDEVs, check [this article](https://pthree.org/2012/12/04/zfs-administration-part-i-vdevs/) and the `zpool` man page.

Answer (score 6):

I know this is an old post. It seems to me the question was about a loop backed ZFS pool. Check [this](http://lxd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/storage/).

Growing a loop backed ZFS pool

LXD doesn't let you directly grow a loop backed ZFS pool, but you can do so with:

```
 sudo truncate -s +5G /var/lib/lxd/disks/<POOL>.img
 sudo zpool set autoexpand=on lxd
 sudo zpool online -e lxd /var/lib/lxd/disks/<POOL>.img
 sudo zpool set autoexpand=off lxd
```